# Entity Framework transaction for multiple edmx data insert

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, transactions

I have an application with multiple edmx. some times I need to insert or update data in different table of different edmx.

Now I'am concern if insertion of data failed after inserting data in one table.

Which can handle by sql transaction but i want do it using Entity Frame work in multiple edmx at once.

Please help me through, i'm giving a sample code alike what i'm working on

```
 public bool SaveInformation(Other_Admission otherAdmission, Account_Bill aBill)
    {

    _aRepository.OtherAdmission.Insert(otherAdmission);  //Assume this is Admission edmx

    aBill.StudentRoll=otherAdmission.StudentRoll;

    _aBillRepository.Bill.Insert(aBill); //Assume this is Account edmx


    _aRepository.SaveChanges();
    _aBillRepository.SaveChanges();

    return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool SaveInformation(Other_Admission otherAdmission, Account_Bill aBill)
{
using (var transaction = _aRepository.BeginTransaction())  
{  
    try  
    {
      _aRepository.OtherAdmission.Insert(otherAdmission);  //Assume this is Admission edmx

       aBill.StudentRoll=otherAdmission.StudentRoll;

      _aBillRepository.Bill.Insert(aBill); //Assume this is Account edmx


     _aRepository.SaveChanges();
     _aBillRepository.SaveChanges();

    return true;
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)  
    {  
        transaction.Rollback();  
    } 
}
```

Comment: @ImtiazRifat, If any error occur that time your transaction is rollback.

Comment: Thank you very much, please can you tell me what happen if there are three edmx like     
 _aDebitCreditRepository.Bill.Insert(aBill);  //Assume this is DebitCredit edmx
and error happen on last one. Does rollback would apply for first two or only in aRepository. like

         _aRepository.SaveChanges();
         _aBillRepository.SaveChanges();
        _aDebitCreditRepository.SaveChanges();  // if Error happen here 
hope i'm able to explain what i want to say.

Comment: https://mkarczewski.wordpress.com/2013/01/04/entity-framework-transactions-multiple-contexts-and-mixing-with-ado-net/

Comment: Thanks again for all of this.